# A second React Router Swtich inside a component not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hey I have a main route `/admin/influencers` in my react app. And when I reach this path I want to display a tab button so user can switch to `/admin/influencers/active` and `/admin/influencers/invited` for example.

here is my implementation:

```
return (
<>
  <div className="header pb-8 pt-5 pt-md-8">
    <Container fluid>
        <Card className="tab-container" fluid={true}>
          <CardBody className="card-body">
            <ButtonGroup className="button-group">
                <Button size="lg" outline color="warning" onClick={() => setSelectedTab(1)} active={rSelected === 1}>Active</Button>
                <Button size="lg" outline color="warning" onClick={() => setSelectedTab(2)} active={rSelected === 2}>Invited</Button>
                <Button size="lg" outline color="warning" onClick={() => setSelectedTab(3)} active={rSelected === 3}>New Verification Request</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
            <img onClick={toggle} className="add-influencer" src={Add} alt="add" width="40px" height="40px" />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </Container>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/admin/influencers/active?page=1"
        component={ActiveInfluencer}
      />
    </Switch>
  </div>
  <AddInfluencerModal toggle={toggle} isOpen={modal} inviteInfluencers={handleInviteInfluencers} updateInvitedInfluencers={fetchInvitedInfluencers}/>
</>
```

);

but this isn't displaying anything. Any help would be aprreciated.
Thank you

Comment: make sure url is changing after u clicked the button

Comment: yes it is changing, but the component is not rendering and I have the exact path entered @InshafAhmed

Comment: Where is the parent router such as HashRouter or BrowserRouter?